# Is there a way to make a link unclickable, but to still use :hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with a CMS that only allows links in the navigation. There is one instance where I have a submenu but there is no page attached.  See below.

1. menu1

   - submenu

     - item1
     - item2
2. menu2
3. menu3

All three top level items (menu 1,2,3) must be clickable + hover.  "Submenu" can't be clickable but the user needs to hover in order to view item1 and item2.

This of course wouldn't be an issue if not for the restrictions in the CMS.  If I add the following CSS then I can't click OR hover.

```
.subMenu {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: I should mention that because of the way the CMS is set up I can't edit the HTML code - CSS and JS only.

Comment: You can use href="javascript:void(0);" in the anchor, or use JS to remove the click handler.

Comment: $(".subMenu").click(function(){ return false });

Answer (score 1):

Try `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:return false;">My unclickable but hoverable link</a>`. Indicating only the "#" as a link should do the trick if your CMS doesn't allow you to specify onclick attributes.

Comment: You can also just use href="javascript:void(0);" and not use a click handler.